# 'the aim of something ... was to' does it mean 'the responsability of something ... was to'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context:

> The fifth organ of the United Nations is the Trusteeship Council. It
> was responsible for monitoring the decolonization process of the 11
> colonies remaining in the world. Its operations formally ended after
> the liberation of Palau.

According to this paragraph, is it true that:

**The aim of** the Trusteeship Council was to liberate colonies that were present around the world.

I feel that the above affirmation is wrong because what I understand from it, is that the Trusteeship Council was responsible for liberating the colonies at that time, which is wrong because its responsibility was only to monitor the decolonization process.

Comment: _Responsible for_ can have two different senses: someone can be made responsible for carrying out a task, or an action of theirs can lead to something else happening (as in _the intruder was responsible for starting the fire_). _Aim_ is appropriate for the first sense, but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

One's responsibilities are the things one must do, or refrain from doing.

One's aim is what is the intended consequence of one's actions.

A teacher's responsibilities include presenting the lessons to the class, keeping order in the class, and ensuring the students do their work, with the aim of having them learn.

Likewise, the Trusteeship monitors the process, its responsibility, with the aim of decolonizing, because the point of monitoring it is to see to it that it happens.  (Since if things had stopped, or reversed, it would not just have watched and noted, it would have raised a red flag.)